# How to get items from JList only when items are selected

Tags: java, swing, list, selection, jlist

In my program - a `JApplet` - I have a `JList` that is populated with a `DefaultListModel`. The user has the choice to select up to a certain number of items and indicate by pressing a `JButton` that he has finished his / her selection. I then use the items selected in the `ActionPerformed` event handler for the `JButton`.

This works great unless no item is selected before the `JButton` is pressed - if nothing is selected the rest of the instructions in my `ActionPerformed` don't operate either. I have tried `myJList.isSelectionEmpty()` as an negative if condition and also compared the array length I get from `myJList.getSelectedIndices()` to 0 but neither work.

However, if something is initially clicked and then deselected (I have a clear selection button), it works and in every subsequent time through the program it works, so it seems to be just the first time that it needs to be triggered.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: sounds like something wrong in your logic - please show a SSCCE (or at the very least the Action that gets executed when pressing the button) that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, this might be one solution.

Initially, disable JButton. Then, provide your JList with ListSelectionListener; inside this event handler, check if the selection is made (at least one item selected). If it is - enable JButton; otherwise disable it. This way you will prevent execution of ActionEvent handler of JButton if no item is selected, which is what you want (I suppose).
Suppose your JList is lstChoices, and your JButton is btnSubmit. This should do the above mentioned:

```
lstChoices.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
        {
            if(lstChoices.getSelectedValuesList().size() > 0)
            {
                btnSubmit.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
            {
                btnSubmit.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```